# how to construct @service in Springboots using a payload variable

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm quite new in spring boots so I hope this is not a silly question

I have a @Service that needs to initiate a class attribute, this attribute needs a information that comes from the RestPayload in the Controller. I'm not finding the most recommend way to do that.

```
     @RestController
    public class UserController {

        @Autowired 
        private UserService userService;

        @RequestMapping("/searchUser")
        public List<UserWrapper> searchUser(@RequestBody UserWrapper userWrapper) {


            List<UserWrapper> returnUserWrapper = userService.findByName(userWrapper);
            return returnUserWrapper;
        }
}
```

And the service layer, I would like to be something like:

```
@Service
public class UserService {
    private LdapTemplate ldapTemplate;
    public static final String BASE_DN = "xxxxxxx";

    @Value( value = "${sample.ldap.url}" )
    private String ldapUrl;

    @Value( value =  "${sample.ldap.base}" )
    private String ldapBase;

    public UserService() {

    }

    public UserService(String dn, String password) {
        LdapContextSource ctxSrc = new LdapContextSource();
        System.out.println(this.ldapUrl);

        ctxSrc.setUrl(ldapUrl);
        ctxSrc.setBase(ldapBase);
        ctxSrc.setUserDn(dn);
        ctxSrc.setPassword(password);

        ctxSrc.afterPropertiesSet(); // this method should be called.\

        this.ldapTemplate =  new LdapTemplate(ctxSrc);

    }
```

The String dn and String password will come in the REST Payload but the other properties comes from a properties file.

Hope someone can guide me with best practices

Comment: After your receive your `dn` and `password` use two `setters`, then call a method that will will call your ldap inside your service.

Answer (score 0):

for ldap authentication you should have a look on spring-security:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#ldap

on the other hand you can access almost any request parameter by just injecting it via a annotation like in these examples:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-requestheader